# Unable to add RxJava dep to gradle

Tags: java, gradle, rx-java

I'm trying use Rxjava and I added it my gradle like so:

However, I'm not able to use it from within my src directory -- the autocomplete doesn't show any suggestions for Observable.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/test/java'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1'
    testCompile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.7'
    testCompile 'io.reactivex:rxjava-math:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'io.reactivex:rxjava-string:0.22.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.0'

}

test {
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2.1'
}
```

I want to be able to use the dependency from within my source directory.

Comment: Was __gradle syncing__ successful?

Answer (score 0):

Once you add a dependency to a **build.gradle** file you need to **build** the gradle project. This downloads all the dependencies and then the autocomplete will show the suggestion.

In **Eclipse** you can do the following:

```
Right Click on Project module-> Gradle->Refresh Gradle project
```

Otherwise from command prompt you can use the following command:

```
gradlew build
```